# Слово "нарочный" - вопросы.

Tags: этимология, фонетика

Вот вспомнилось в связи с определенными обстоятельствами это слово. И сразу всплыли из памяти вопросы.

1. Оно обозначает человека, с которым передают что-либо. Какие-либо еще значения есть?
2. Насколько я понимаю, что это прилагательное. Или все-таки существительное (ну, как "ванная", "столовая")?
3. Как правильно произносить: на́рочный или наро́чный? Почему произносится именно так, как укажете? В смысле - как это можно аргументировать.
4. Каково происхождение этого слова? Оно имеет отношение к наречию (?) "наро́чно"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I.
1.НА́РОЧНЫЙ1 (нарошный), нарочная, нарочное (прост.). Не случайный, сделанный с намерением. Нарочное посещение.  
2.НА́РОЧНЫЙ2 (нарошный и нарочный; нарочный обл.), нарочного, муж.
 a. Гонец, посылаемый с каким-нибудь важным и спешным поручением (ист.).
 b. Служащий почты, доставляющий телеграммы в места, удаленные от почтово-телеграфных контор.

Это по Ушакову. У Даля даны только значения 1. и 2a., Викисловарь даёт аж три значения у прилагательного, но по-моему все 3 дублируют друг друга. В остальных, найденных мной, словарях только 2a.

II. В значении 1. - прилагательное *В штабе красногвардейских отрядов указали, в какую именно комнату ему следует явиться, волокита казалась **нарочной**, придуманной для пущей важности, но спорить он не стал.* (Б. Л. Васильев, "Дом, который построил Дед"), в остальных значениях - существительное.

III. Если существительное, то только нАрочный [чн]. С прилагательным сложнее. Ушаков даёт ударение на первый слог, но если б мне потребовалось его произнести, то сказал бы нарОчный(шн) (ср. нарОчно), тоже самое советует и Викисловарь. Кстати, по Далю ударение и у существительного и у прилагательного стоит на втором слоге (нарОчный). Причину смещения ударения в существительном, думаю стоит искать, в стремлении канцелярита избавится от любой омонимии.

IV. Да, это родственники и произошли от слова "нарокъ" (намеренние, цель). Раньше существовало 2 способа отправки сообщений - нарочным посыльным (специально уехал передать письмо или посылку) и с оказией (кто-то едет в туже сторону). Из первого сочетания и вышло существительное "нарочный". Прилагательное же сохраняет связь с наречием до сих пор.

Comment: По п. III - подразумевается, что ударение сместилось под влиянием наречия?
По п. IV - то что надо, спасибо.

Comment: @gecube, Я думаю, что ударение на первый слог в существительном сместилось под воздействием стремления канцелярских работников избежать омонимии с прилагательным. У Даля в обоих случаях ударение на "о". Но это только моё непроверенное предположение.

Comment: Можно добавить, что слово нарокъ в Словаре
Академии Российской находится в кусте слова
"речь", ведь "нарок" мы понимаем не только
как цель или намерение, но и как озвученный
приказ, наказ, поручение. *Выслушать
нарекание от старшего. Выучить заданный
урок. Дать себе твердый зарок.*

Answer (score 0):

~2. Существительное. Субстантивант от прилагательного. 
~3. на́рочный. Аргументация  - словарь.
~4. Ну в общем-то имеет. иак чказать двоюродное родство. В основе  - рок (судьба).